# Chage text in first bracket that are succeded by third/square brackets

Tags: regex, sed

I want to append some text (.html) at the end of line in format `[some_text](some/other/text)`; basically links in markdown syntax.

Example

```
[Test](test/link) would be [Test](test/link.html)
[Test](test/link1/link) would be [Test](test/link1/link.html)
[Test] would be [Test]
(test) would be (test)
```

So I was trying out unix `sed` with syntax: `sed -i 's/\[*\](*)/.html)/g' filename.md`. The said `sed` syntax is wrong and not working, can someone help? I'm open to using other tools like `awk` or `perl`, it is appropriate for this scenario.

**Solution**: `sed -i 's/\(\[[^][]*]([^()]*\))/\1.html)/g' filename.md`

Suggested by @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Can you have more than one match in a single line?

Comment: Maybe `sed 's/\(\[[^][]*]([^()]*\))/\1.html)/g' filename.md`?

Comment: @Sundeep no. Only one match per line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -i 's/\(\[[^][]*]([^()]*\))/\1.html)/g' filename.md
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/YQ56Ll).

The regex is a [POSIX BRE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) expression that matches

- `\(\[[^][]*]([^()]*\)` - Group 1:

  - `\[` - a `[` char
  - `[^][]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
  - `]` - a `]` char
  - `(` - a `(` char
  - `[^()]*` - zero or more char sother than `(` and `)`
- `)` - a `)` char.

The `-i` option makes the replacements in the same file provided as input file in a GNU `sed`. `g` flag will look for all matches on the lines.

Answer (score 3):

Based on given samples:

```sh
$ cat ip.txt
[Test](test/link)
[Test](test/link1/link)
[Test]
(test)

# if closing ) should also be matched: sed -E 's/(\[[^]]+]\([^)]+)\)/\1.html)/'
$ sed -E 's/\[[^]]+]\([^)]+/&.html/' ip.txt
[Test](test/link.html)
[Test](test/link1/link.html)
[Test]
(test)
```

- `\[` match `[`
- `[^]]+` match one or more non `]` characters
- `]\(` match `](`
- `[^)]+` match one or more non `)` characters
- `&` backreferences entire matched portion
- `\1` backreferences portion matched by first capture group

With `perl`:

```sh
perl -pe 's/\[[^]]+]\([^)]+\K(?=\))/.html/'
```

- `\K` helps to avoid capturing the text matched until that point
- `(?=\))` is a lookahead assertion to match `)` character, this also is not part of the matched portion

Add `-i` option for either solutions once it is working as expected.